# Can't run exe file using ProcessBuilder depending of computer

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have come across a problem while working with Process and `ProcessBuilder` in Java.

I have a line of code looking like this :

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("des.exe", String... params);
```

It works fine on my personal computer, but not on my testing server and I can't figure out why.

The ErrorStream give me this:

```
des.exe: MZ����@���: not found 
des.exe: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Both computers are on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with java 1.8.

Any idea where it might come from?

Comment: Have you tried executing the program on the server by hand? It doesn't look like it's a problem with the ProcessBuilder, just that des.exe doesn't work on the server.

Comment: I did using wine, and it worked perfectly

Comment: and are you also executing Java using wine?

Comment: No, I ran tests on both computers using maven

Comment: Well, I do not know why it works on one computer, but on the server I suspect it does not recognize it as valid executable, or at least does not start it with wine. Try `wine des.exe`.

Comment: I already tried and it worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for the difference is that the file format of windows executables is not registered with the [`binfmt_misc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst) handler in the kernel, which allows the kernel to execute various programs through helpers transparently. The error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` typically means that the file got handed off to `/bin/sh`, instead of to wine.

So, check if the binfmt_misc file system is mounted (most modern linuxes do this automatically):

```
grep binfmt_misc /proc/self/mountinfo
```

should return some entries (might be autofs, might be binfmt_misc depends on the distro).

if it isn't then mount it:

```
sudo mount -t binfmt_misc binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

you can tell what's registered by looking at the content of this directory. To register for running dos executables with wine you need to register it:

```
echo ':DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/bin/wine:' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

Once registered, executing the binary should happen transparently, and it should succeed through the ProcessBuilder.

Configuring this for the server at boot time is left as an exercise to the user.

If you want to skip this entire mess, then you can change the execution from `des.exe` to `wine` with the first argument of `des.exe`.

Comment: That was it. Wine was not registered, I don't know why. It works fine now.  Thanks alot !